# Randomize divs (pause on hover + click function)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm working on a simple website which fades between random divs, one at a time.

I've managed to work out how to cycle through the divs randomly, but I need help to **pause the animation on hover** and add a function that **manually changes the div on click**. Any ideas on how to add these functions to the code below?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  (function randomFade() {
    var fadeDivs = $('.item'),
      el = fadeDivs.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * fadeDivs.length));
    el.fadeIn('slow').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow', randomFade);
  })();

});
```

```css
.item {
  display: none;
}

.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <div class="box" style="background:red">
    ONE
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div class="box" style="background:green">
    two
  </div>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <div class="box" style="background:blue">
    THREE
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please add more code for better understanding?

Comment: Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wngrtzk/so9p657u/)

Comment: Any ideas? @Nick

Comment: I am working on it, and try to resolve your problem but somehow i have issue with the fadeIn() and fadeOut() functions on mouse hover but still i try to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

something like this might work

```
$(document).ready(function () {
(function randomFade() {
    var fadeDivs = $('.item'),
    if (!fadeDivs.is(":hover"){
        el = fadeDivs.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * fadeDivs.length));
        el.fadeIn('slow').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow', randomFade);
    } else {
        setTimeout(function () {
            randomFade
        }, 3000);
    }

})();
});
```

Or you might be able to just do this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   (function randomFade() {
       var fadeDivs = $('.item'),
       if (!fadeDivs.is(":hover"){
           el = fadeDivs.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * fadeDivs.length));
           el.fadeIn('slow').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow', randomFade);
       }
   })();
   $('.item').mouseleave(randomFade);
});
```

Looks like the is hover wasn't working. If i add a an idand reference the id it will cause it to stop. Its working inconsistently so there is a problem with it. the below code doesn't restart it either

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    (function randomFade() {
        var fadeDivs = $('.item'),
            el = fadeDivs.eq(Math.floor(Math.random() * fadeDivs.length));
           if(!($("#item").is(":hover"))) {                
              el.fadeIn('slow').delay(3000).fadeOut('slow',randomFade);
           }

    })();
 });
```

Comment: Made this jsfiddle, maybe it could help? [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/wngrtzk/so9p657u/)

Comment: That was helpful. I update the code a little. Not working 100% but hopefully that gives you something to build off

Comment: Hmm.. Neither the pause or the click function works for me with that code. Thanks for the suggestion though!

Answer (score 0):

I use your code as example and add 2 more elements in `HTML` for better output and also make changes in `jQuery`.

I also add the functionality to **pause on hover**, **restart on mouse leave** and **restart animation on div click**.

Here is what i try. Please have a look and try this.

```js
var interval = null;
var elementClick = false;
function randomFade(stop = false) {
    var randomDiv = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('.item').length);
    if(stop == false){
        $('.item').fadeOut(1000).delay(1000).eq(randomDiv).fadeIn(1000);
    }else{
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
    console.log('Random Div : ', (randomDiv + 1));
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    randomFade();
    interval = setInterval(function(){
        randomFade();
    }, 3000);
});

$( "div.item" )
  .click(function(){
    console.log('Mouse Click');
    elementClick = true;
    interval = setInterval(function(){
        randomFade();
    }, 3000);
  })
  .mouseenter(function() {
    if(elementClick == false){
        console.log('Mouse Enter');
        clearInterval(interval);
        randomFade(true);
    }
  })
  .mouseleave(function() {
    if(elementClick == false){
        console.log('Mouse Leave');
        interval = setInterval(function(){
            randomFade();
        }, 3000);
    }else{
        elementClick = false;
    }
  });
```

```css
.item {
  display: none;
}

.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
    <div class="item">
      <div class="box" style="background:red;color:white;">
        ONE
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <div class="box" style="background:green;color:white;">
        TWO
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <div class="box" style="background:blue;color:white;">
        THREE
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <div class="box" style="background:coral;color:white;">
        FOUR
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="item">
      <div class="box" style="background:GRAY;color:white;">
        FIVE
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I hope this will works for you.